# Why does running TASKKILL result in this error: “Taskkill: ERROR: Invalid namespace.”

Tags: cmd.exe

When I try to use `TASKKILL`.

```
TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe
```

I get this error.

```
ERROR: Invalid namespace
```

Even the tasklist is not working.

```
TASKLIST
```

I also get that error message.

How can i fix this problem??

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the correct tags for you windows version.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running `chkdsk`, [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Also run deep antivirus scans by your anrivirus and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with this:

First, opening the cmd.exe as an administrator, then please run:

```
cd \windows\system32\wbem
net stop winmgmt
rename Repository Repository.old
net start winmgmt
```

Some applications may have installed things that weren't rebuilt automatically, please run:

```
cd \windows\system32\wbem
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
```

Comment: You just saved my day! I would like to know some rudimentry basics what was going on.